# Creating docker container with Jetty and Cassandra

Tags: docker, cassandra, jetty, dockerfile

Installed docker on Cent OS using the steps mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/)

So far I can run docker images of jetty and cassandra independently by following the steps mentioned [Jetty](https://hub.docker.com/_/jetty/) & [Cassandra](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/)

---

I want to create a docker container which will have `Cassandra database` and a web application running in `Jetty server` which interacts with this database.

I'm able to create docker container with Jetty and able to run some sample web application with in jetty using the following `Dockerfile` content

```
FROM jetty
RUN mkdir /var/lib/jetty/webapps/test-app
COPY index.html /var/lib/jetty/webapps/test-app/
```

and once I save this file as Dockerfile I issue the following commands to create docker image and run the same

```
docker build -t test-docker .

docker run -d -p 8443:8080 test-docker
```

now I can see the same outcome of this application in my browser using

`<ip_address>:8443/test-app/index.html`

**Question:**

How I should be able to integrate Cassandra database with in this docker image and run the complete `Jetty + Cassandra + Web Application` packaged as a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Docker Cassandra Documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/) instead of running cassandra with

```
docker run --name some-cassandra -d cassandra:tag
```

mention all the ports that cassandra uses so that the same can be communicated or interacted from external resources like below

```
docker run --name some-cassandra -d -p 7000:7000 -p 7001:7001 -p 7199:7199 -p 9042:9042 -p 9160:9160 cassandra:tag
```

Now my web application running in Jetty Container can access the Cassandra database using Java Driver.

**Note:** if you are using Cassandra version > 3.0 then you should use `cassandra-driver-core` of version >= `3.0`

Maven dependency for `cassandra-driver-core`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and `cassandra-driver-mapping`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cassandra Official Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/), to start cassandra database. Start your web application in a seperate container as you are doing right now.

You can link cassandra container with your web application container

```
docker run --name webapp --link cassandra:cassandra -d test-docker
```

You need to use cassandra hostname/container IP in the webapplication. You can pass the cassandra DB_URL as environment variable.

```
docker run --name webapp --link cassandra:cassandra  -e DB_URL='cassandra:7000' -d test-docker
```

Read more about [Docker container Linking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/)